# How to prevent .htaccess inheritance?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

AFAIK by default all .htaccess files in all directories leading to the file requested are parsed, i.e. in this setup:

- `DOC_ROOT = /usr/local/www/data`
- `AllowOverride` is set to `All` in the above directory

if a file at `/dir1/dir2/dir3/file` is requested, all folders from `/` down are being checked for `.htaccess`. If the file is found it is parsed and then the execution is continued based on combined contents of the `.htaccess` files.

So here's my setup:

- `DOC_ROOT = /usr/local/www/data` - that's where all static and php files are kept.
- there's a `.htaccess` in the `DOC_ROOT` that rewrites all but some requests to index.php.
- there's a `/Python/root.wsgi` in the `DOC_ROOT` and in httpd.conf there's this: `WSGIScriptAlias /apps /usr/local/www/data/Python/root.wsgi`

As you can imagine I do not want .htaccess to be used at all for the /Python folder, but it is. How do I prevent it?

I tried setting this in httpd.conf, but it doesn't do the job:

```
<Directory "/usr/local/www/apache22/data/Python">
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

If I do put .htaccess in the Python folder with `RewriteEngine off` that seem to do the job, but I don't want to be forced to put such a file in each of the subfolders I don't want to root .htaccess to be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way to disable inheritance, sadly. An easier way could be to create a single folder in your web root for "everything else", and in the .htaccess in there, put the `RewriteEngine off` statement.

I think you can do something with `RewriteCond` to disable this. If you want all subfolders to just be accessible (and rewrite anything that doesn't match an existing subfolder), you can use `RewriteCond !-d`.

Comment: And you cannot change this via AllowOverride option?

Comment: To answer my own question - AllowOverride works on a per-dir basis, i.e. if set to None on a folder, that's a sub-folder of a one that has it enabled, it's parent's .htaccess will be parsed, but its own not.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set this in the root of your site's .htaccess on a per-directory basis.

So say you have a subdirectory "Python" you would add this to .htaccess in your DOCROOT.

RewriteRule ^Python/.*$ - [L]

Comment: I've been staring at this, can just cannot figure out what it does. It seems to rewrite `https://Python/.` to `https://Python/.` . But that makes no sense. It rewrites that particular subdirectory request to itself (hyphen means no change), and all other URLs to themselves. In other words, it does nothing. Yes? No?

Comment: @DavidSpector note the [L] at the end of the line. That will stop any further rewrites that the Rewrite engine might have otherwise done.

Comment: The rewrite engine has needed a debugger from the very start. It is already inefficient; keeping a log of each rewrite could have been done. Incredible how some old implementations are not improved over time.